# Is there any way to know every sentence executed in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, logging

I need to know if there is any way to know every sentence executed in a SQL Server 2005 database. That is because I have a registry modified in a concrete date, and I would like to know the sentence executed to update the registry. Of course, if I could have more information besides the sentence, it would be great!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Nothing is tracked/traced *by default*, so if you're looking for something *now* that happened `x` days ago, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your statement has been executed in the very recent past, this query will get you the last few executed statements and may be of use.

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME (dest.dbid) DatabaseName, 
    deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], 
    dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest

ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

If you know when the statement gets executed, and want to capture all SQL statements at the time, then you can use the Profiler to Trace all activity.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx